# Best normalised practice to map phone numbers with user or office

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am designing a DB in MySQL. I have a user table, office table and a phone number table as I intend to allow multiple phone numbers to a user or for an office. so I know I need to add foreign keys in phone number table to office table and to user table rather than the other way round. But how do I do it without a null record? 
What is the best-normalized way to make this with neither officeId not userId in the phone number record null?

MY Phone number table

```
CREATE TABLE `phonenumber` (
  `Id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SchoolId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_Phone_User` (`UserId`),
  KEY `FK_Phone_School` (`SchoolId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Phone_School` FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolId`) REFERENCES `school` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Phone_User` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `user` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My User Table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `Id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `DisplayName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OfficialName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserName` (`UserName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My School table

```
CREATE TABLE `school` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `AddressId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_School_Address` (`AddressId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_School_Address` FOREIGN KEY (`AddressId`) REFERENCES `address` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: if both values are null, just set them to null and whenever the phone number is used you update the record

Comment: `PasswordHash` of length 50 is not a good sign. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as your default "string" column type and only limit the length if absolutely necessary. Use `INT` as your primary key, auto-increment type, not usernames. Those can and will change which will mess up your database if you're not prepared.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a compromised hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @tadman I'm using a GUID/UUID as primary key, not the username. So no issues. I will update the Hash column. thanks,

Comment: MD55 is compromised???

Comment: @JinsPeter MD5 was compromised ages ago and SHA1 has been shown to be deeply flawed. Neither are suitable for password hashing because they are designed to be *fast*. Password hashes are engineered to be slow, painfully so if necessary. There's a whole bunch of MD5 discussion where people are playing games and making collisions, but [here's a quick summary](https://blog.avira.com/md5-the-broken-algorithm/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to allow for `NULL` **fields** during the creation of the `Phone_numbers` table. What you were warned against is having a whole *record* with `NULL`s. You are correctly handling the **field** that but not saying anything or saying `NULL`. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Phone_numbers(
phone_number    VARCHAR(15)    NOT NULL,
user_id         INT UNSIGNED,
office_id       INT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (phone_number), 
CONSTRAINT RefUsers1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES Users(user_id),
CONSTRAINT RefOffices2 FOREIGN KEY (office_id)
REFERENCES Offices(office_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB
;
```

For this simple model
[image]

Comment: Is this answer any different from what I have done.? My actual concern is that I have read in some best practice docs that having a null in any column of any record is bad. (Allowing null can be done as business need though.) In this case here, when I have an office phone number record, The userId is null, When I have a user phone number record, office Id is null. Is there a way to avoid that.?

Comment: You can't avoid it **IF** you want to keep one table for phone numbers. Users and Offices are different entities and if they are NOT related, then you either need two (2) phone tables or need to combine the users and offices table and add a Type (U/O). Having a NULL is not a bad thing, AFAIK. It's a solid way to flag, non existent or irrelevant data.

Comment: You do not have a `NULL` record, but a `NULL` **field**.  `NULL` fields are OK!